# Creating a set of columns from rows using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that currently looks like this:

```
   Year  Country Subject Descriptor  GDP
0  2015  Austria                  r  344.2
1  2015  Austria                  n  344.2
2  2015  Austria                  d  100
3  2015  Austria                  u  5.742
4  2015  Belgium                  r  416.7
5  2015  Belgium                  n  416.7
6  2015  Belgium                  d  100
7  2015  Belgium                  u  8.483
```

I want to transform it to look something along these lines:

```
   Year  Country GDP_R GDP_N GDP_D GDP_U
   2015  Austria 344.2 344.2 100   5.742
   2015  Belgium 416.7 416.7 100   8.483
```

So far I have attempted to use melt and stack but I feel like I'm just missing it, if you can help me here it'd be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first use `groupby.agg()` and put all values of GDP column in a list. Then, you can convert the object to a new DataFrame, using as columns the prefix 'GDP_' and all the values of the Subject Descriptor column.

Finally, putting the two together using `pd.concat()` will give your final output.

Please see below an example:

```
one = df.groupby(['Year','Country'])['GDP'].agg(list).reset_index()
two = pd.DataFrame(one['GDP'].to_list(), columns=['GDP_' + s.upper() for s in set(df['Subject Descriptor'].tolist())])

new = pd.concat([one,two],axis=1).drop('GDP',axis=1)
```

`new` prints back:

```
   Year  Country  GDP_D  GDP_N  GDP_R  GDP_U
0  2015  Austria  344.2  344.2  100.0  5.742
1  2015  Belgium  416.7  416.7  100.0  8.483
```

Comment: Thank you so much this worked exactly how I needed it to!

Answer (score 0):

First you can use `groupby` on `['Year', 'Country']` and next you can convert the GDPs for each group to a list and then transpose them to columns. Last few steps are to rename columns, reset index and remove column axis name.

```
(
    df.groupby(['Year', 'Country'])
    .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.GDP.tolist(), index=x['Subject Descriptor']))
    .rename(columns = lambda x: f'GDP_{x.upper()}')
    .reset_index()
    .rename_axis('', axis=1)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pivot in this case :

```
 (df.pivot(['Year', 'Country'], 'Subject_Descriptor', 'GDP')
    .rename(columns = lambda col: f"GDP_{col.upper()}")
    .rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()
  )
 
   Year  Country  GDP_D  GDP_N  GDP_R  GDP_U
0  2015  Austria  100.0  344.2  344.2  5.742
1  2015  Belgium  100.0  416.7  416.7  8.483
```